# How to write multiple feature file and step definition file into Calabash project directory?

Tags: ui-automation, calabash, calabash-android

To write multiple feature files(.feature) and respective step definition(.rb) files for my current Calabash project directory. Here, My doubt is that

a. Do I need to create feature file manually by using text editor after default single feature file creation based on calabash cmd 'calabash-android gen'?

b. Should I use my IDE to add multiple feature file and step definition files into Project skeleton?(I'm using Visual Studio Code IDE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a. For your first feature you can reuse the file that is created if you want to. After that you should create a new file for each feature you want to test.
When you execute the tests you will often only execute 1 feature test at a time while developing and perhaps only from a certain line number. So having the tests split in multiple fetaures works well.
You have probably read it but if not please take a look at the [Github page](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android).

b. You can create the files any way you want to. I normally copy an existing feature file through IDE and clean it. Personally I find JetBrains Rubymine to be a really good IDE for working with Calabash.